# PHP part in Python based website

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I need to write a small addition to a Python+Django based website, hosted on Google Apps. Trouble is that I don't have any experience with Python.

The addition is pretty straight forward, it requires little database access
So  thought of 2 possible solution's:

1. Quickly dive into Python and get it done with Python.
2. Run PHP on Quercus and write this particular addition in PHP, then somehow combine it into the website as a dingle PHP page.

Edit: There is another option I thought of:

1. Writing it in PHP and hosting it on an external server, embedding it in an iframe. The addition I am writing has no need to be SEO friendly, so an iframe will have no negative effect on the website.

What do you suggest?

Comment: I think the clear winner is #1... and i say this as a PHP developer and lover :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about how you will run php on GAE since it only support Java and Python.
I'd go with solution 1. Python isn't hard to apprehend, you should find ready-to-go code snippets in GAE documentation, and its Datastore doesn't seem too hard to use :D

there's a nice tutorial in GAE documentation: [here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html)

Answer (score 1):

Quercus on App Engine runs on the Java runtime, while Python runs on, er, the Python runtime. While you can run one app with multiple runtimes, they have to be different major versions, which means that communication between them will be awkward - you'd have to make URLFetches between them.

I think you'll find it's far simpler to learn enough Python to make the changes. And trust me, you won't regret learning Python. ;)

Comment: I've been looking at Python for quite long, I am definitely going to learn it. 
Thanks for the advice, unfortunately the client thought its just something "minor", and opened wide eyes when he received the proposal, so the manger decided to let it go... Shame I really work on it.

Comment: Speaking of learning, I thought of going into C first, since I climbed from the top to the bottom (HTML > CSS > JS > PHP). C will give a solid foundation for the high level languages as well as NET.